# Insert Variable Into Temp Table Field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a snippet of what I am trying to achieve, but it shows the error I am hitting.  I am setting a variable equal to a value, and attempting to insert that value into a temp table in my select statement, but it errors with 'Invalid Column Name' each time.  How could I insert a variable into a field in my temp table and get past this error

```
SET @Name = 'JJ Jet Plane'
Create Table #DataHold (ID Int Identity not null, city nvarchar(1000), country nvarchar(1000), name nvarchar(1000))

Insert Into #DataHold(city, country, name)
Select city, country, @Name FROM database1
WHERE profit >= 10000

SELECT * FROM #DataHold
```

Comment: Assuming database1 is a table, does it contain the fields city, country, and profit?

Comment: Yes database1 is a table and it does contain the fields.

Comment: There is nothing else wrong with your example - your real problem has something you're not showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works - my guess would be that your source table (`database1`) has a different definition; perhaps a typo in one of the column names?  Can you provide the DDL (create table statement) for that table so we can check it?

```
declare @database1 table (city nvarchar(1000), country nvarchar(1000), profit money)
insert @database1 
select 'London', 'UK', 10
union select 'New York', 'US', 10000
union select 'Paris', 'France', 99999

declare @Name nvarchar(1000)

SET @Name = 'JJ Jet Plane'
Create Table #DataHold (
    ID Int Identity not null
    , city nvarchar(1000)
    , country nvarchar(1000)
    , name nvarchar(1000)
)

Insert Into #DataHold(city, country, name)
Select city, country, @Name FROM @database1
WHERE profit >= 10000

SELECT * FROM #DataHold
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `create table` syntax is wrong - you need to supply types for all the columns, e.g.:

```
Create Table #DataHold 
(ID Int Identity not null, 
 city varchar(100), 
 country varchar(100), 
 name varchar(100))
```

Comment: You are correct, sorry that is why I should copy/paste not try to type it. - But I will still receive the error.